# Perfect matching in a 2-regular graph

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

Is it true, that in every $2$-regular graph with $14$ vertices there is a perfect matching ? If you think it's true - prove it, otherwise show counter-example

This is my exercise. I think that it's true because it doesn't matter how do you draw this graph, it always will be a cycle, and because the cycle has even number of vertices there always will be a perfect matching.

Comment: You might have left out an assumption of connectedness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Try making it a pair of $7$-cycles.

Comment: oh my god. I am so embarrassed. Thank you.

Comment: @You’re welcome. (I think that we’ve all had that feeling a time or two.)